# Root user consume huge amount of CPU

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage

I can't understand why root user take huge CPU load, since there is no special processes running.

## `top -c`

[image: "top -c" command results]

Comment: That could be an exploitative mining process (like for Bitcoin or other cryptocurrencies). Most processes do not hide their name. You could check (netstat, tcpdump) if the application does any network traffic.

Answer (score 6):

If your company has a breach response process, I would invoke that now.

Otherwise:

This looks potentially malicious, I would recommend looking at it closer in `/proc`.

With a root privilege shell, either via `su` or `sudo -s`, change into the directory `/proc/{pid}`. Changing `{pid}` for the pid shown by `top`, `30530` in this case.

There are many things to look at to get a clue about this process, here are a few:

**`exe`** : link to executable that started this process. `# readlink -f exe`
**`cmdline`** : command line that started this process. `# cat cmdline | tr \\0 \\n`
**`environ`** : environment variables in this process. `# cat environ | tr \\0 \\n`
**`fd`** : directory of links to open files and sockets.

Unless you can find a reason it's legitimate, I'd kill it via `kill -9 {pid}` and investigate as a potential breach.

Comment: It might even be worth an `strace` or a `pstack` on the process to see what it's up to.